# ACER ASPIRE ONE, WIFI Atheros Communications Inc. AR9462 problem with 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, indicator, aspire-one

I have an **Acer Aspire One AO756-Series**, equipped with a wifi controller
**Atheros Communications Inc. AR9462**

Everything worked fine on 12.04, but when I upgraded to 12.10 I experimented some issues :

- wifi does work!
- still, the wifi icon/menu does not react normally :

  - it is always grey, hence not indicating if connected or not,
  - It does not react to me clicking on it (disconnect, change the network,
    desactive wifi, etc)

So it's not a critical issue because I can change the active wifi connection through control pannel, but it is very annoying.

Do you know of an solution around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

One solution with Acer V3 571G (card AR9462) is to configure the `ath9k` module with options: `nohwcrypt=1`

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

The file should contain this:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1 blink=1 btcoex_enable=1 enable_diversity=1
```

After saving this modified file, do

```
rmmod ath9k
modprobe -b ath9k
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, spurious listings get added to /etc/network/interfaces during an upgrade. Network Manager assumes you will therefore be managing those interfaces; in your case, wireless, and not NM. Please check:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

If there is anything more in there than this, remove it:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now your wireless should be correctly managed by NM.